# How can I export / import a single keychain item via the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, security, keychain

OS X has a command line tool called [security](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) that is made for working with keychains. The [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) has examples of how to export all items of a specific type / all items for a specific keychain - but I don't understand how to export / import a single item.

What I would really like to do is update the password on a single `IPSec XAuth Password` item but I think maybe exporting, possibly deleting, then importing would be the closest thing to what I want.

I haven't had any luck finding examples or related questions for this task, and I've not used the `security` tool other than to list available keychains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find-generic-password or find-internet-password:

```
security find-generic-password -l 'keychain item name'
security find-internet-password -s accounts.google.com
```

-l mathes a label and -s matches a server string. Add -w to only print the password.

Comment: you are awesome! is there any way to change the stored value (i.e. save it back into the keychain?)

Comment: did you find an answer to importing it back in?