# export single keychain item without ui

Tags: macos, security, passwords, keychain, keychain-access

Sadly I have problems with OS X and the UI just won't load. But I have ssh access to my machine. I would like to reinstall OSX but I have forgotten my Time Machine password. It is saved in the keychain though. I have read the manpage of security and this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/679168/how-can-i-export-import-a-single-keychain-item-via-the-command-line-in-os-x) but can't get the `-w` option to work to print the password. I am using the following command `sudo security find-generic-password -w -a "F3754F03-B291-4F1B-B44F-9C8A755B180D"` in several variations e.g. -aw -wa and so on. it doesn't print the password, doesn't throw an error. it just runs and there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ssh access to your machine, you could the login.keychain and the metadata.keychain file in ~/Library/Keychains/ on a your new mac in the same place

Just do

```
# scp username@host:~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain ~/Library/Keychains
# scp username@host:~/Library/Keychains/metadata.keychain ~/Library/Keychains
```